# Why is code deploying saying instances are too few or unhealthy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Im using codebuild, codepipeline and code deploy on AWS. I want code deploy to deploy a built java jar to an ec2 which is part of an ASG. Pulling the code from github and building goes fine but once code pipeline gets to the deploy phase it pauses for about 5 minutes then fails and gives this message.

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
>   failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
>   deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
>   experiencing problems.

I have followed these docs perfectly several times over but still get the error.

[Integrating code deploy with auto scaling groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html)

[Create/configure ec2 auto scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-auto-scaling-group-create-auto-scaling-group.html)

[Deploy the application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-auto-scaling-group-create-deployment.html)

Its as if the deploy stage in code pipeline just doesnt pick up the artifact because no events happen and there is no terminal output durig the deploy phase. It just hangs and then fails 5 minutes later. When i click on the link for the old experience Aws routes you to an old version of code deploy and there I can see an error code

> Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS

But otherwise I dont see any other information. Ive looked at this link too. [explanation for health concerns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/error-codes.html?icmpid=docs_acd_console#ecode_health_constraints) ... But still is no help because I have tried those things and still the problem persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been at this for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

I added tags and it started working. In my case despite them being optional, they were necessary to deploy the application.